# How to encrypt in Java and decrypt in Android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, encryption

I have a Linux server running a Java-jar file that encrypts several files.

The Android and iPhone App download that file and shall decrypt it. What algorithm I have to use to do so?

I recognized that the algorithms I used in Java do not work in Android. What I did in Java was:

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}
```

what didn't work in above code?
Any alternatives?

Comment: "What did not work" is not only textually incorrect, it is a horrible description as well. What did try do on the client side? How did you transport the ciphertext?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS:

I use NSString+AESCrypt (https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC)

Sample:

```
NSString* encrypted = [plainText AES256EncryptWithKey:@"MyEncryptionKey"];
NSString* decrypted = [encrypted AES256DecryptWithKey:@"MyEncryptionKey"];
```

Android (AES256Cipher -  https://gist.github.com/dealforest/1949873):

Encrypt:

```
String base64Text="";
try {
    String key = "MyEncryptionKey";
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    byte[] cipherData;

    //############## Request(crypt) ##############
    cipherData = AES256Cipher.encrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, passval1.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    base64Text = Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Decrypt:

```
String base64Text="";
String plainText="";
try {
    String key = "MyEncryptionKey";
    byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    byte[] cipherData;

    //############## Response(decrypt) ##############
base64Text = User.__currentUser.getPasscode();
    cipherData = AES256Cipher.decrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, Base64.decode(base64Text.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
    plainText = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");            
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: In Objective-C exceptions are **only** used for non-recoverable programming errors and are considered non-recoverable. (Distributed Objects are the exception).

Comment: This had be stumped, the default behaviour on AESCrypt-ObjC is to use nil IV, and in java you have to explicitly set a blank byte array and shown here. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The link below gives a nice example of encryption and decryption using Symmetric key encryption.

The symmetric key used is a custom plain text.
This helps if we need to to decrypt using a IOS device.
The example uses a AES 128 bit encryption. Note that it uses IV parameters.
Since the encryption is 128 bit the length of the key should be 16.

On Android side the same method implementations can be used since the language is Java. In IOS **CommonCryptor.h** can be used for encryption decryption.

http://www.java-redefined.com/2015/06/symmetric-key-encryption-ios-java.html

Comment: Answers should contain the code, not point to an another site. Further the question contained the code to encrypt with Java.